# Memento Implementation in VBA

Tags: java, .net, vba, design-patterns, memento

I'm looking for a VBA implementation of the Memento pattern (GoF). I'm looking at converting the Java version [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). It will be used for Undo/Redo functionality for an Excel add-in.

Specifically, I am having difficulty with the line:

```
return new Memento(state);
```

Or, to make it more specific, can someone rewrite this in VBA:

```
public Memento saveToMemento() {
    //System.out.println("Originator: Saving to Memento.");
    return new Memento(state);
}
```

The entire code that I am trying to convert is available at the Wikipedia link above.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific as to what your problem actually is? The use of the `return` keyword? The use of the `new` operator?

Comment: Dirk, I've re-written the question and included new information, so hopefully now you can understand where my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` keyword in Java is very different to the `return` keyword in VBA. In VBA, `return` is paired with `gosub` as a way of altering the flow of execution within a procedure.

In Java, `return` means "exit from function" and either returns a value of an appropriate type (as in your example) or returns nothing (in the case of a `void` function - Java equivalent of `Sub` in VBA).

In your example, it is going to return an object of type `Memento`. This must be either the return type of the function or a subtype of that return type. A new object is created through use of the `new` keyword (similar to the `new` keyword in VBA). The object called `state` is passed to the constructor of the new object as a parameter.

In VBA you could write this:

```
Function saveToMemento(state As String) As Variant

saveToMemento = createMemento(state)

End Function
```

where `createMemento` is a function you have written to create an appropriate structure to hold the memento information

Comment: barrowc, How do I create the constructor of the new object (as parameter), or more specifically, how to write the createMemento function so that it emulates the Java code for saveToMemento?

Comment: You can define classes in VBA and then create objects of those classes. VBA doesn't have constructors as such but you can use `Class_Initialize()` to initialize the object. Unfortunately you can't pass parameters to that `Sub` so you would have to call a separate `Sub` to deal with setting the initial state. You might get some ideas from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227509%28VS.60%29.aspx